# Numpy way of appending the data retrieved from for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for the numpy way of appending the data retrieved from for loop as in the example below:

```
import glob, gdal, numpy as np

tiff_files = glob.glob('*.tif')

all_data = []   #LOOKING FOR ALTERNATIVE HERE
for f in tiff_files:
    data_open = gdal.Open(f)
    data_array = data_open.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)
    all_data.append(data_array)  # #LOOKING FOR ALTERNATIVE HERE
```

The above code works, but would be better to append the data_array retrieved from for loop directly into the numpy array rather than using python list. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: you don't like the list or the for-loop?

Comment: thinking that numpy array would be faster than the list since the number of input files are thousands.

Comment: Is `data_array` from each file the same size?  If so you could insert each array into a master array 1D larger.  You'd have to initialize that array before looping over the files.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, data_array from each file the same size. waiting see your  complete code

Comment: At the end of this, should `all_data` be an array, or list of arrays?  Or does it matter?  How are you going to use `all_data`?

Comment: building the list of arrays, and converting that back to a array at the end (only if needed) does better in timings than inserting arrays into a large prebuilt array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it a one-liner:

```
np.array([gdal.Open(f).ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32) for f in glob.glob('*.tif')])
```

but making data in a `ndarray` is not faster than the builtin `list`. E.g:

```
In [391]: timeit a=[0]*1000
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.1 us per loop

In [392]: timeit a=np.array([0]*1000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 265 us per loop
```